# Trouble with request mapping attribute with restful service

Tags: spring, rest, annotations, code-reuse

I have a whole bunch of methods as shown below in a class.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/person/foo" method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/xml, application/json")
public @ResponseBody Person update(@RequestBody final Person person) {
      //
}
```

I want to put the annotations at the class level so my methods look like below:

```
@RequestMapping(value="foo") // for Post requests
public @ResponseBody Person update(@RequestBody final Person person) {
      //
}
```

Most of my methods are POST, so I use that at the class level. The methods that are GET, I want to put it at the method level.

But it doesn't work. Some of the Post methods work, but GET methods don't work at all.

Comment: `it doesn't work` => it does not map there? you don't get params passed? another problem? Also can you post a method that "does not work"?

Answer (score 1):

If you have `@RequestMapping` defined at the class level e.g.:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping( value="/person" )
public class BeautifulPeopleController { ... }
```

You cannot make *some* of the methods to ignore it => **all** of the methods would assume they are prepended with `/person`.

Here is from the `@RequestMapping` API [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html):

*Method-level mappings are **only allowed to narrow** the mapping expressed at the class level (if any)*